# jQuery Cicle : Is it possible to paginate with multiple elements per page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I'm trying to setup a simple pagination with the [jQuery Cicle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle) and the pager method.

I'm applying it to a list of elements. By default, it shows only one element per "page". How can I show as many as I want (5, 10, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 5, 10 etc elements in DIV and animate DIVs (containers)